# Illustrator: locking a single object – what's the quickest/most efficient way to re-unlock only that object again?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, workflow

I find my workflow for temporarily locking/unlocking single objects to be very awkward. I often refrain from this operation since the process of re-unlocking *only that, one, particular* object at a later stage, is simply too cumbersome.

I assume you can relate to what I'm referring to, but for clarity, here's my typical use case:

You're inside a tangled mixture of paths, groups, objects… trying to prevent affecting this *one, particular object*, while working on others. Once you hit `Command-L/Ctr-L` on that object… continue working… then sometime later want to revert the locked state on that *one, particular object*, you're pretty much screwed, having to either:

1. **Locate the needle in the haystack** (Layers palette) prior to unlocking it… or
2. **Unlock All** with `Command-Opt-2/Ctr-Alt-2` which is obviously pretty stupid, since you only wish to (referring to the scope of this question) unlock that *one, particular object* under your mouse cursor.

…You can't just **right-click on the locked object and select unlock**.

So:

### What's your workflow for this operation – how can I improve it?

Comment: Fantastic question, and I wish you could right-click and unlock. Seems intuitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Hit v to select the selection tool
2. Object > Unlock all... (Command/Ctrl-Option/Alt-2)
3. Shift-Click the object you want to keep unlocked
4. Object > Lock > Selection (Command/CTRL-2)

Seems to be the fastest, easiest method here.

Basically you unlock all locked objects, remove one object from the selection, then re-lock everything else.

Comment: Once the muscle memory is locked in, it's very quick.

Comment: Scott: that's a great answer, exactly what I was looking for. Alan's note on muscle memory, however, is also spot on… :)

Comment: Glad to help hced. #1 is optional since you can simply do a Command/Ctrl-Shift-click at #3.

Comment: In the case of a small number of multiple objects (say 5 out of 250), it might also help to do a Save Selection, and then choose that saved selection after going through the above steps.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugIn from [ASTUTEGRAPHICS](https://astutegraphics.com/)

Here is a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3BDGA5QKw0&list=PLVuiTl_w4-zBgJbN9tr9Ik0MgwWLhH4sF&index=10) for it.

It's called SubScribe and brings you a couple of features plus a new icon in the Tools-Bar: it's a lock/unlock-Symbol.
I experimented with a tiny Script I did myself to solve this problem too. Select an Object, hit a special key to start the script and it's locked. The Problem was unlocking.

Of course you have to tell Illustrator which Object to unlock, therefore again a selection. But a selecion on an already locked Object would only be the highlight in the layers panel. In The end it was not a time saver. Get the PlugIn if it bothers you so much.

Comment: Seems like Adobe is working on this feature, OMG