# Is there a shortcut to unlock image instead of trying to find it in layers? Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, creative-cloud

I have an image thats locked on a layer but I am not sure which layer it is. Is there a way to direct select the image to unlock it instead of trying to hunt through my layers trying to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object > Unlock All` or <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>

There's no method to unlock only *one* locked objects. But you can unlock all, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click the object you need unlocked, then <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to lock everything else again.

Related, if not a duplicate: [Illustrator: locking a single object – what's the quickest/most efficient way to re-unlock only that object again?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6222/illustrator-locking-a-single-object-whats-the-quickest-most-efficient-way-to)

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with paid plugins, Astute's SubScribe has a [lock-unlock tool](https://astutegraphics.com/learn/tutorial/subscribe-new-features-overview). $100/y for their whole suite.

Comment: While I love Astute tools.. *realistically*... this, in itself, is hardly worth a $100 subscription in my opinion.

Comment: Probably not, unless you deal with a zillion locked objects on a zillion layers every day. Then maybe it is. I think there's like two tools in their suite that singlehandedly justify about half of the cost for me.

Comment: Oh they have a *ton* of useful stuff.... not devaluing Astute plugins in *any* way. I use them daily. I just think for this particular use, the cost outweighs the usage.